# Why is my RxJS Observable completing right away?

Tags: node.js, express, reactive-programming, observable, rxjs5

I'm a bit new to RxJS and it is kicking my ass, so I hope someone can help!

I'm using RxJS(5) on my express server to handle behaviour where I have to save a bunch of `Document` objects and then email each of them to their recepients. The code in my `documents/create` endpoint looks like this:

```
    // Each element in this stream is an array of `Document` model objects: [<Document>, <Document>, <Document>] 
    const saveDocs$ = Observable.fromPromise(Document.handleCreateBatch(docs, companyId, userId));

    const saveThenEmailDocs$ = saveDocs$
      .switchMap((docs) => sendInitialEmails$$(docs, user))
      .do(x => {
        // Here x is the `Document` model object
        debugger;
      });

    // First saves all the docs, and then begins to email them all.
    // The reason we want to save them all first is because, if an email fails,
    // we can still ensure that the document is saved
    saveThenEmailDocs$
      .subscribe(
        (doc) => {
          // This never hits
        },
        (err) => {},
        () => {
          // This hits immediately.. Why though?
        }
      );
```

The `sendInitialEmails$$` function returns an Observable and looks like this:

```
  sendInitialEmails$$ (docs, fromUser) {
    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {

      // Emails each document to their recepients
      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        mailer.send({...}, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            observer.next(doc);
          }
        });
      });

      // When all the docs have finished sending, complete the
      // stream
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
```

The problem is that when I subscribe to `saveThenEmailDocs$`, my `next` handler is never called, and it goes straight to `complete`. I have no idea why... Inversely if I remove the `observer.complete()` call from `sendInitialEmails$$`, the `next` handler is called every time and the `complete` handler in subscribe is never called.

Why isn't the expected behaviour of `next` `next` `complete` happening, instead it's one or the other... Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Johnny, have you ever been able to solve this? I know I answered late, but was it your solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that `mailer.send` is an asynchronous call.
Your `observer.complete()` is called when all the asynchronous calls have been launched, but before any of them could complete.

In such cases I would either make an stream of observable values from the docs array rather than wrap it like this.

Or, if you would like to wrap it manually into an observable, I suggest you look into the library async and use

```
async.each(docs, function(doc, callback) {...}, function finalized(err){...})
```